# How do I restore UEFI boot entries in BIOS?

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi

I have a protectli vault fw4 mini PC running Untangle NG Firewall. It failed to boot after I had to forcefully power it off when the web UI was unresponsive. I plugged the device in to a monitor and saw the Untangle boot menu start followed by a brief message about `failed to read sector <random hex code>`. And then a restart.

Thinking the 32GB mSata SSD drive might be failing I switched the UEFI firmware settings to legacy mode and booted a UBCD usb stick. I was able to successfully run a surface (read) scan on the drive without issue.

From that point on, I switched the BIOS back to UEFI mode and it refuses to see the drive’s boot entries.

I created a Linux System Rescue disk and was able to run `fsck` on all three partitions. It did fix several issues on the main partition. Hopefully this is why it was having reading sector errors (strange for a logical problem).

The disk has 3 partitions.

1. /dev/sda1 - Linux Filesystem
2. /dev/sda2 - Linux Swap
3. /dev/sda3 - EFI System

On `/dev/sda3` I see the following folder structure…

```
/EFI
— debian
—— grubx64.efi
— untangle
—— grubx64.efi
```

The system is obviously a Debian based system.

I assume the problem is that changing to legacy mode erased the boot entry in the UEFI firmware. What is the proper way to add this boot entry back to the UEFI firmware with Linux tools / commands? I found some info about first listing the entries with `efibootmgr` but only the bootable USB stick is found.

The UEFI firmware menu itself does not have an option for adding manual entries that I see. Any other information needed?

Answer (score 0):

I found I was able to use the following command to restore the boot entry.

```
efibootmgr -c -p 3 -d /dev/sda -L “UEFI: Untangle” -l “\EFI\untangle\grubx64.efi”
```

Unfortunately, now that it boots I still get the failed to read sector error.

Comment: You can also generally register/add UEFI boot entries via the Boot tab within the UEFI firmware settings. For the sector issue on an SSD, that would seem to imply either the data on the sector is corrupted _(try [`TestDisk`](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) to recover the data)_ or the sector has reached its end-of-life _(check the S.M.A.R.T wear leveling value: `smartctl -a /dev/<disk>`)_

Comment: @JW0914 thanks. No option in UEFI settings. It turns out a long test failed on the drive. I went ahead and replaced it.

Comment: I wanted to verify, in the UEFI firmware settings, there's no _Add_ option for adding boot entries _(that would be highly abnormal if the case, as that function is there to allow registering new boot entries that don't use the built-in EFI boot digital certificate(s) stored in the firmware, as without that signature, you can't Secure Boot)_?

Comment: @JW0914 there is no option. Maybe secure boot was disabled, although I think I remember seeing it enabled. At this point the device is back in service, so I can’t check.